# Enable extension for one store and disable for other store view in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Basically the scenarios are 
I have two store view one is for Pakistan and the other is for America. I want to enable the extension for one store and disable for other store?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can do it by changing the store view and disabling the extension from the extension configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to "Store->Configurations", open the module configurations and then click on "Store View" and change it to the respective store and set it "Enable" or "Disable" accordingly.

[image]

Comment: when i select storeview e.g America ,the configuration page not display my module which i have added in it .

Comment: Which means, you haven't added system.xml and config.xml file for your module's configurations. Please add it as a best practise and use the "status" field to check either module is enable or disable

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <Extrafee>
            <Extrafee>
                <status>1</status>
            </Extrafee>
        </Extrafee>
    </default>
</config>

Comment: add a system.xml file in etc/adminhtml folder with setting of enable, disable. 


<field id="status" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1"
                       showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Extra Fee</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
                </field>

Comment: i have added system.xml file .Everything is working fine but when i click on store view ,the extension tab which i add not display there

Comment: system.xml needs to be etc/adminhtml and config.xml needs to be in etc/ . Check if status field has this variables. showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1"

Comment: both files are in the same location which u suggest

Comment: Can you clean cache, run static:content deploy once and try. It should work. working for me.

Comment: Share a screenshot of both of the files code once.

Comment: Thanks alot  for helping me out ,there is a little mistake which i correct.i am going to mark your answer as accepted

Comment: Thanks Usman. I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

A Magento 2 module can only be enabled/disabled globally.
In shell `php bin/magento module:` you see the commands available for enable/disable.

It is common that you can have different configuration for different store views but you can not disable a module for a store view.

Check the admin settings for the module and see if there is any leads to inactivate features in the module for a specific store view.